# Exercise 2.2. ii of Riehl's book "category theory in context"

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma

> **Exercise 2.2.ii.** Explain why the Yoneda lemma does not dualize to classify natural transformations from an arbitrary set-valued functor to a represented functor.

I don't understand the meaning that "Yoneda lemma does not dualize to classify natural transformations"; Could you explain what it means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She's asking you to say why the Yoneda lemma does not imply that there is a natural bijection
$$\mathrm{Hom}(F,\mathsf{C}(c,-)) \cong Fc$$
for a functor $F : \mathsf{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$ and an object $c$ of $\mathsf{C}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand!